# What does "_current_limit" or "_current_grid_direction" do?

Tags: attributes, collection, toolbar

I'm in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php and I see lines like the following:

`$dir = $this->_getData('_current_grid_direction');`

`$limit = $this->_getData('_current_limit');`

Yet when I search the app, I don't see mention of these values anywhere else.  Where are these attributes used?  Why does nothing else set them?  How can I know what other attributes might exist for a collection?  How can I know what values are accepted for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes are used in the Product List Toolbar on the frontend. `_current_grid_direction` holds data as to whether the product list is currently sorted in Ascending or Descending direction. `_current_limit` holds data as to how many items show on the current page, aka, per page limit of products to show.

You can see these items in use in the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`

`_current_grid_order` is used in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::getCurrentOrder()`. That function is called in the following functions in the same class:

```
getOrderUrl
isOrderCurrent
setCollection
```

`_current_grid_direction` is used in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::getCurrentOrder()`. That function is called in in the following functions in the same class:

```
setCollection
```

That function is also called in the following files:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

If you start stepping through the code from toolbar.phtml you should be able to see it in action.

Comment: Can you offer more about where I might see them used on the frontend in a code-oriented manner?  Or will I find them in the dashboard somewhere?  If so, where?

Comment: Answer updated. From there, you need to step through the code because if you take a look at the files and functions I pointed out, there are very clear usages of these pieces of data that should be relatively easy to understand. I hope this helps!

Comment: I see it now!  So they are arbitrary names used to set up convenience getter methods.  :)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right. You should be able to override them to, Im pretty sure I did that in one of my modules.